# How to cerate horizontal image slider in App screen?

Tags: adobe, adobe-xd

I am working on a photosphere application and am create tutorial screen.

I want horizontal image slider in tutorial screen so How to cerate horizontal image slider in screen.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Make Repeat Grid. Then Click on Scroll Group(Shift +Alt +h).Fixed the location. Then Click on present button.
[Here's My Link:](https://xd.adobe.com/view/14f3579d-d4d0-4af1-9b2b-218a03ee9e4b-41a0/)